# How to escape special character in exec_command in python

Tags: ssh, python

I am trying to connect from one server to another server using paramiko. Here is the code:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, username='abc', password='password')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ssh xyz@host1 ls')
```

I am unable to run the above code because of the special character "@". Could someone suggest me how to resolve it.

I am able to run `ssh xyz@host1 ls` command in putty successfully. But through python code it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The username and host are specified in your `ssh.connect` so there's no need to do `ssh xyz@host1`. You can just do:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, username='abc', password='password')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
```

`ssh.connect` is establishing the connection so you don't need to execute ssh again.